# Is it safe to transport meat in a coolbox with ice?

Tags: food-safety

If you buy say sausage rolls and pork pies on a Thursday and keep in the fridge overnight, then travel Friday for 5-6 hours with them in a cool box with ice blocks, then put them back in the fridge Friday overnight, then serve up for buffet on the Saturday, is this too many temperature changes over 2 days?

Comment: Baking meat in bread casings used to be a method of preservation (eg, cornish pasty, empenadas).  I don't know if modern techniques are still the same and act as a sufficient preservative, or if there are other issues such as different bacteria or other problems today vs. back then.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have enough ice to keep them cold the whole time, that's the same as just putting them in your fridge for a couple days: they'll be chilled, stay chilled, then get served, whether warmed or just naturally brought toward room temperature.

So be sure you have enough ice, and as usual be sure not to let them sit out forever to serve, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Sarah Sure, it'll be okay even without heating, but... are you really serving them at refrigerator temperature?

Comment: They would be bought cooked for a buffet

Comment: I understand they're already cooked. I was just assuming that you wouldn't want to eat cold rolls and cold pies, so you'd heat them up at least a little to serve for the buffet. Again it doesn't matter, if you've kept them chilled they'll be safe cold or warm or hot, I just said "heated and served" because you asked about the number of temperature changes and I figured there'd be one for serving.

Comment: No I appreciate your advice, I just didn't want to make anyone I'll, thankyou again

Comment: Sausage rolls and pork pies are common on cold buffets, put out striaght from the fridge normally (UK).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57678/discussion-on-answer-by-jefromi-transportation-of-meat).

Answer (score 2):

When packing your cooler, put the ice above the products that need to be kept cold.

If you can find it, "dry ice" is better than conventional ice, as it doesn't melt into water.  Dry ice also doesn't need to be placed above the item, as the cold doesn't just go down.  The gas it releases fills the whole space, chilling the whole cooler.

A 5 inch by 5 inch square, 1 inch thick will typically last for 24 hours.  Multiple squares will increase the time that it can keep the product in a "below 41°F" condition.

( For those who cant obtain dry ice. Use 2 garbage bags to use for your normal ice to help ensure your food does not get as wet as it would otherwise. (( food will get a bit if condensation with double bagging the ice reguardless ))   ) Added. 4/25/2017. VIA joes' opinion

Use gloves when handling the dry ice as it causes instant freezer burn on bear skin. I recommend a polymer blend glove, leather and cloth sticks to the dry ice. Do not use latex or food service gloves to handle the dry ice as instant freezer burn penetrates the thin layer protection anyways

For your length of trip, normal ice should be plenty, but make sure it's on top of what you're transporting, and for either ice you need to use an appropriate container. 
It is best to wrap the dry ice so it does not touch bare food that causes freezer burn aswell, i recommend wrapping the dry ice in bubble wrap but leaving 1 5 inch by 1 unch side open facing the middle of the container.

Dry is is the best when transporting food safely because it is waterless, lasts a long time in a sealed enviornment handling needs to be diciplined to remaind unscathed but besides the few extra steps (to protect your self its the way togo).  Added. 4 25 2017

Comment: This answer seems like it could be really useful if it were more clear. If you have time, I'd like to try to understand exactly what you're trying to say.  Meet me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan)?

Comment: @Jolenealaska : I think I understood what they're trying to convey, and cleaned it up some.  "product" in this case is the food to be kept cold.  I did change some of the "container" mentions to "cooler".  I should also mention that if you're putting water ice above something, you want to make sure it's in a good bag, or the food is well-sealed, so you don't end up getting the food wet.

Comment: Joe. Good point bag your foods that should not get wet